# Divs do tamanho da janela

Tags: html, css

Tenho um mapa abaixo de uma `div`. Meu problema, é que quando adiciono `altura 100%`, ele pega o valor de `body`, mais abaixo da `primeira div`, aparecendo `scroll`.

Exemplo: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1jw36qk2/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Directly accessing Street View data</title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      .conteudo{width: 100%; height:100%;}
    .um{width:100%; height:100px; background: red; float: left;}
    .mapa{width: 100%; height:100%; float:left; background: green;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
       <div class="conteudo">
           <div class="um"></div>
           <div class="mapa"></div>
       <div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Como faço para não pegar este Scroll, eu quero que as duas DIVs fiquem 100% em relação a janela.

Comment: Não entendi o que quer exatamente ? Você quer que não apareça o scroll?

Comment: @MagicHat Isso mesmo, as duas Divs devem mostrar-se no window, sem ultrapassar o body, com exemplos semelhantes aos usados abaixo... ATT

Comment: Se a resposta estiver correta, poderia validá-la, ou qualquer outro ajuste comenta, para ajustarmos..

Comment: Ela esta correta. Tentei buscar outras formas de fazer isso, mas até o momento não consegui... ATT

Comment: É que não sei exatamente o que pretende, são muitas variantes...Mas por exemplo , se a div um for tipo um header se pode por px no height e position:fixed e a mapa com 100% no height...mas vai ter efeitos colaterais tmb... o que exatamente quer?

Comment: Como você citou acima, terei uma div semelhante a uma Header, e a outra que deve ficar abaixo de acordo com o window (Mapa).  Irei usar num Iframe, dai ele se ajusta automaticamente ao tamanho do Iframe que a pessoa criar, sem ter SCROLL. Eu utilizei do CALC, mas fiz um script com Jquery com Resize. Minha grande pretensão era deixar apenas com css, mas algo que funcionasse em qualquer navegador. ATT

Comment: então usa fixed...e na hora do iframe se dá um padding ou margin descontando o header...

Comment: Fiz os testes aqui... Deu certo com fixed. Ficou um pouco gambiarra para dar padding e não gerar scroll (box-sizing: border-box;). Mas acredito que tenha dado certo. ATT

Comment: Sempre tem uma gambi aqui outra ali,,,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que acontece é o seguinte:

Você está definindo a `div mapa`, com `height:100%`, porém você tem mais `100px`na `div um`, então seu conteúdo terá `100% + 100px` na altura. E quando a altura do conteúdo ultrapassa a altura da janela o browser dispara o `scroll`.

Existem várias soluções vou passar 2.

1- Definir ambas alturas com porcentagem.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Directly accessing Street View data</title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      .conteudo{width: 100%; height:100%;}
    .um{width:100%; height:25%; background: red; float: left;}
    .mapa{width: 100%; height:75%; float:left; background: green;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
       <div class="conteudo">
           <div class="um"></div>
           <div class="mapa"></div>
       <div>
  </body>
</html>
```

2- Definir o primeiro `height` com `px` e o segundo com a sobra.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Directly accessing Street View data</title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      .conteudo{width: 100%; height:100%;}
    .um{width:100%; height:100px; background: red; float: left;}
    .mapa{width: 100%; height: calc(100% - (100px)); float:left; background: green;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
       <div class="conteudo">
           <div class="um"></div>
           <div class="mapa"></div>
       <div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Lembrando que sempre que o conteúdo do `body` for maior que a janela irá disparar o `scroll`. E ainda pode usar `overflow: hidden`, para esconder a diferença.
Qualquer dúvida comenta que agente ajusta.

Comment: Ótimas dicas. Eu conhecia as duas, mas a primeira não irá me servir, pois no meu caso, terei que utilizar PX. Já a segunda é uma boa opção, mas tenho medo de usá-la por não ser compatível com navegadores. Acredito que com Transition seja capaz também, mas será que existe alguma maneira, que seja compatível com todos os navegadores? usando position com margin-top negativo, como janelas modais... não sei, conhece algo mais compatível? Ainda fico com o CALC... ATT